# Erro em DateTime.TryParse()

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com um problema com uma conversão utilizando o código abaixo:

```
        string vcto = "29/01/2018";
        DateTime data;

        Boolean resp = DateTime.TryParse(vcto, out data);

        if (resp == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERRO NA CONVERSAO");
        }
```

Ele esta retornando `false`. porém a data esta correta.

Não tenho acesso à máquina que esta executando o código, somente verifiquei via *log*. Na minha máquina de desenvolvimento funciona perfeitamente.

O que pode fazer o `TryParse()` falhar? A data esta correta.

Comment: O input ser diferente do que o informado na pergunta?

Comment: Você tem como ver qual o idioma da máquina? Ela pode estar configurada em um idioma diferente, provavelmente inglês. Você pode testar isso trocando o mês pelo dia no input.

Comment: Por que não utiliza o : Convert.ToDateTime() ?

Comment: Amigo verifique se não é a cultura do seu servidor, já tive problemas com conversão de data por esse motivo.

Comment: @ViniciusMatos porque seria um erro fazer isto, ele está parcialmente correto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem que adicionar a cultura específica para a aplicação saber que tipo de dado ela está esperando, no caso imagino que esteja esperando a brasileira, então seria isto:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        if (!DateTime.TryParse("29/01/2018", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), DateTimeStyles.None, out var data)) Console.WriteLine("ERRO NA CONVERSAO");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oRgJeX). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tuX4GJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Culture/Convert.cs).

Documentação do [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__).

Funciona na sua máquina porque ela já está configura assim, nem todas estão.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas - Funcionar é diferente de estar certo]

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, como verificio qual cultura o windows esta configurado? Seria nas configuracoes regionais. O que mais cheguei proximo é o item que se refere a formatação de datas. Teria mais alguma coisa para verificar?

Comment: Não, é lá mesmo, mas isso nada tem a ver com programação, não importa para o programador como está o Windows de alguém.

Comment: Manieiro, descuple mas nao entendi muito bem... mas pelo que entendi algo na maquina esta fazendo o erro ocorrer devido este item de cultura nao seria isto? Gostaria de verificar qual cultura esta. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não, seu programa está errado, não é problema na máquina de ninguém, cada deixa a máquina como quiser, é o seu programa que tem que cuidar disso certo.

Comment: Ok Obrigado Maniero!

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
string vcto = "29/01/2018";
DateTime data;

Boolean resp = DateTime.TryParseExact(vcto, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out data);

if (resp == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERRO NA CONVERSAO");
}
```